# how to fit Large String into jLabel

Tags: string, swing, jlabel

how to break the String at each 100th characters in Jlable.
i have tried

```
 String str = "rgwueiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiigthytjtjhyfghgfthythtyrhyrhythryhiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiithurgtihiugtgoeim9yv8umv9,u,j89,9v8juv98yliv9ki9kj9bjj9iki9hkiykhvivjkinv";
     String parsedStr = str.replaceAll("(.{100})", "$1\n");
     System.out.println(parsedStr);
     jLable1.getPreferredSize();
     jLable1.setText(str);
```

String is broken. but it is not Showing in Jlable as broken

Comment: Try HTML: `jLabel.setText("<html>"+str);`

Comment: solved it.. using jLabel.setText("<html>"+parsedStr+"<br/></html>");     thanx by the way

Comment: @pawansharma Add it as your own answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it using

```
 String str = "rgwueiiiiiiiiiiiiu       j89,9v8juv98yliv9ki9kj9bjj9iki9hkiykhvivjkinv";
     String parsedStr = str.replaceAll("(.{50})", "$1\n");
     System.out.println(parsedStr);

     text.setText("<html>"+parsedStr+"<br/></html>");
```

By The Way thanx